# Loading Picture into image Delphi

Tags: delphi, image

Hello I am currently working on a program and I would like to add a button that would allow the user to Load a picture from his computer into the Image

```
procedure TForm1.btnLoadPicClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 img1.Picture.LoadFromFile( 'test.1');
 img1.Stretch := True ;
```

I was using this code but it limits the person to only being able to use that specific picture and I would like him to select one from his Computer thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

You need to display an open dialog:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TOpenDialog.Create(self) do
    try
      Caption := 'Open Image';
      Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofFileMustExist];
      if Execute then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: For nitpicking, in a construct like `Create/try/.../finally/Free/end`, it's better to omit the owner (Self) and use `Create(nil)`. It would avoid sending a flurry of unnecessary notification messages throughout the application.

Comment: You could even use a `TOpenPictureDialog` so users can see a preview while choosing a file. That component still exists nowadays, doesn't it?

Comment: @François: Sometimes a component needs an owner for other reasons than being destroyed, e.g. poOwnerFormCenter.

Comment: @Ulrich Gerhardt: Right, but I would say extremely rarely, and not even necessary with `poOwnerFormCenter` when the owner is the MainForm. And not at all in this case.

Comment: what is Image1 ? where is it declared?

Comment: @LionsFan: I have just dropped a `TImage` control on the form.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand props to you for remembering this 8 years later lol

Answer (score 1):

First place a Timage and an OpenPictureDialog on your form and then on your uses clause add jpeg. Then on click event of btnLoadPic put the code as

procedure TForm1.btnLoadPicClick(Sender: TObject);

Begin

```
    If not OpenPictureDialog1.Execute Then
       Exit;
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
    //If not (Image1.Picture.Graphic is TJPEGImage) Then

    //raise Exception.Create('File not JPEG image');
```

End;

If you want only the JPEG image then uncomment the commented lines. In the object inspector you can set the Timage property Stretch to True.

Answer (score -1):

To open a graphical file so that the user can select the file himself, the `TImage`, `TOpenPictureDialog`, and `TButton` components must be placed on the form.

Place the following code in the button's click handler:

```
If OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
```

To open the jpeg and png files at the top of the code, in the line uses we need to add the name of the two libraries, `JPEG`, `PNGImage`.